# How to re-connect WP files in lampp/htdocs to new SQL database to recover site under development

Tags: database, wp-config, localhost, xampp

First time here, facing a bigtime wordpress situation. My Ubuntu installation crashed beyond repair during upgrading version. Managed only to copy the wordpress files, installed in **/opt/lampp/htdocs**, cause I'm developing in localjost.
There was **no salvage of mySQL directory** in Ubuntu installation, as it was beyond my skills in cli-linux, so it is gone for good...

What have tried so far, is creating a new database with same name as the old one, and copied wp-config.php and all files to the folder where reinstalled wordpress. I get "Error Establishing a Database Connection".

Is there anything to be done, e.g recreating database with same name in mySQL to link wp-config or wp-content, and link Wordpress file folder to new database?
Furthermore, if it is possible to link wp files to a new database,how to access site with all passwords lost?

Please inform me, before starting over the development of the site.

Comment: You will need to run the WP installer again, new users, new passwords, new everything. Delete your `wp-config.php` after backing it up and run the 5 minute install, then you can create a new user and start recreating the posts and pages

Comment: @Tom J Nowell, I know the wp installation procedure. Since mySQL is gone without a backup, I cannot log in to my under development site. I need to mention, that I have only the wp files in /opt/lampp/htdocs, not the initial database, wp installation was linked too. I'm asking for a way to not recreating the website from the beginning.

Comment: There is nothing to login to, you have to do a fresh install to the DB from scratch using the standard install instructions. If you do not have the database then you do not have a site. You cannot recreate the site from just files. I'm really sorry but your data is gone, unless you can find a copy of the database or a backup you're going to have to recreate the database from scratch

Answer (score 0):

If you have no database backups then you're going to have to start from scratch. The database cannot be recreated from the uploads folder and plugin/theme files.